# Lsof command in repeat mode no interval

Tags: unix, monitoring, lsof, timing

How can you set the timing of lsof to sub 1 second? On lsof -r (repeat mode), is the minimum value 1 second? Is there a way to have a continuous monitoring with lsof without having intervals between 2 consecutive lsof command in order to check which user had accessed specific file?

Answer (score 2):

If you dont have `inotifywait` installed, (which is ideal for this), then you can get closer to real-time if you combine `lsof` with `watch`:

`$ watch -n0.1 lsof`

This updates every `0.1` of a second.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor in "real time" any file accesses under the current directory, open a terminal and run:

```
inotifywait -r -m -e access --format '%w%f' . | while IFS='' read -r fname; do [ -f "$fname" ] && lsof "$fname"; done
```

Or, as spread out over multiple lines:

```
inotifywait -r -m -e access --format '%w%f' . | while IFS='' read -r fname
do
    [ -f "$fname" ] && lsof "$fname"
done
```

This requires an OS, such as linux, which supports `inotifywait`.

The body of the `while` loop can be replaced with anything that suits your purpose.

The meaning of the options to `inotifywait` are:

- `-r`

  Monitor recursively through subdirectories.
- `-m`

  Monitor continuously.
- `-e access`

  Monitor ACCESS events.  There are many possible events that might be of interest but this appears to be most closely matched to what you asked for.
- `--format '%w%f'`

  Write the path and file of each accessed file to standard out.
- `.`

  Monitor the current directory, `.`.

#### Limitation

The above code does not handle file names which contain newline characters.  To handle that, one needs to use inotifywait's `-csv` option along with more code that understands the subtleties of CSV format.